# How to send a message to "Wechat group" programmatically from my app?

Tags: android

I want to programmatically send a message to any wechat group/contact from my app. From a lot of research I have found this piece of code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "yyyuu jij kio");

            sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.tencent.mm");
            if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) == null) {
//                Toast.makeText(this, "Error/n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            }
            context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

But it is too not  working. I have also came to know that wechat has official API's but they are only available in china, so is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `But it is too not working` how exactly?

Comment: It just opens the select group list window on wechat, user has to manually select the group .

Comment: looks like that is all you can do without using API. you may want to try to decompile their app, and see which parameters except `EXTRA_TEXT` it supports.

Comment: oh, so where i can found these parameters? In Menifest or some other file?

Comment: I'd look in the launcher activity

Comment: ok thanks, I will try and let you know :)